# GridSearchCV & BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, gridsearchcv

I'm running a GridSearchCV for NLP data, this is the code I'm using:

```
%%time
# Next we can specify the hyperparameters for each model
param_grid = [
    {
    'transformer': list_of_vecs, 
    'scaler': [StandardScaler()],    
    'model': [LogisticRegression()],
    'model__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'model__C': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
    },
    {
    'transformer': list_of_vecs, 
    'scaler': [StandardScaler()],
    'model': [DecisionTreeClassifier()],
    'model__max_depth': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
]

# Train the GridSearch
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)

fitted_grid = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I've already run the GridSearch successfully once without any issue with fewer hyperparameters just to make sure it would run, but I started to suddenly get this error after I added a few more model__parameters and it only appears after about an hour of the code running. Any idea how I can fix this?:

> exception calling callback for <Future at 0x1da7efdba60 state=finished
> raised BrokenProcessPool>
> joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback:  """
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py",
> line 407, in _process_worker   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 117,
> in get
> res = self._recv_bytes()   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line
> 221, in recv_bytes   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line
> 323, in _recv_bytes   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line
> 345, in _get_more_data MemoryError """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ### Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky_base.py",
> line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
> callback(self)   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py",
> line 359, in **call**
> self.parallel.dispatch_next()   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py",
> line 794, in dispatch_next
> if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py",
> line 861, in dispatch_one_batch
> self._dispatch(tasks)   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py",
> line 779, in _dispatch
> job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib_parallel_backends.py",
> line 531, in apply_async
> future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\reusable_executor.py",
> line 177, in submit
> return super(_ReusablePoolExecutor, self).submit(   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py",
> line 1115, in submit
> raise self._flags.broken joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has
> failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the
> function are all picklable.
>
> _RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
> _RemoteTraceback:  """ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py",
> line 407, in _process_worker   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 117,
> in get
> res = self._recv_bytes()   File "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line
> 221, in recv_bytes   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line
> 323, in _recv_bytes   File
> "C:\Users\Alfredo\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line
> 345, in _get_more_data MemoryError """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> BrokenProcessPool                         Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py in
> fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
> 889                 return results
> 890
> --> 891             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
> 892
> 893             # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py in
> _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)    1390     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):    1391         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
> -> 1392         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))    1393     1394
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py in
> evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
> 836                     )
> 837
> --> 838                 out = parallel(
> 839                     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
> 840                         clone(base_estimator),
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in **call**(self,
> iterable)    1054     1055             with
> self._backend.retrieval_context():
> -> 1056                 self.retrieve()    1057             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done    1058
> elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
> 933             try:
> 934                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
> --> 935                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
> 936                 else:
> 937                     self._output.extend(job.get())
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib_parallel_backends.py in
> wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
> 540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
> 541         try:
> --> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
> 543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
> 544             raise TimeoutError from e
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py in result(self, timeout)
> 443                     raise CancelledError()
> 444                 elif self._state == FINISHED:
> --> 445                     return self.__get_result()
> 446                 else:
> 447                     raise TimeoutError()
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py in __get_result(self)
> 388         if self._exception:
> 389             try:
> --> 390                 raise self._exception
> 391             finally:
> 392                 # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky_base.py in
> _invoke_callbacks(self)
> 623         for callback in self._done_callbacks:
> 624             try:
> --> 625                 callback(self)
> 626             except BaseException:
> 627                 LOGGER.exception('exception calling callback for %r', self)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in **call**(self,
> out)
> 357         with self.parallel._lock:
> 358             if self.parallel._original_iterator is not None:
> --> 359                 self.parallel.dispatch_next()
> 360
> 361
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in
> dispatch_next(self)
> 792
> 793         """
> --> 794         if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
> 795             self._iterating = False
> 796             self._original_iterator = None
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in
> dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
> 859                 return False
> 860             else:
> --> 861                 self._dispatch(tasks)
> 862                 return True
> 863
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self,
> batch)
> 777         with self._lock:
> 778             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
> --> 779             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
> 780             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
> 781             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib_parallel_backends.py in
> apply_async(self, func, callback)
> 529     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
> 530         """Schedule a func to be run"""
> --> 531         future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))
> 532         future.get = functools.partial(self.wrap_future_result, future)
> 533         if callback is not None:
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\reusable_executor.py
> in submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
> 175     def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
> 176         with self._submit_resize_lock:
> --> 177             return super(_ReusablePoolExecutor, self).submit(
> 178                 fn, *args, **kwargs)
> 179
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py
> in submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)    1113         with
> self._flags.shutdown_lock:    1114             if self._flags.broken
> is not None:
> -> 1115                 raise self._flags.broken    1116             if self._flags.shutdown:    1117                 raise
> ShutdownExecutorError(
>
> BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure
> that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by removing the `n_jobs=-1`. However, I am not sure how to fix and also allow parallel processing. Another thing you could try is to set the `pre_dispatch`. It controls the number of jobs that get dispatched during parallel execution. The default value is 2 times the `n_jobs`. Thus, it could be overloading your processing queue. I had a case like yours, and I have set the `n_jobs = -1` and the `pre_dispatch = '1*n_jobs'`. This worked for me.